# Ajax request is not working inside of boostrap form validation

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, bootstrap-4

I am implementing a form using Bootstrap validation, I had made the validation works without problems but when all is validated and is the moment to send the data to my API the AJAX Post be don't execute, the catch clause don't take any error and only the ajax part of the section don´t execute this is my validation code:

```js
        (function () {
            'use strict';
            window.addEventListener('load', function () {
                // Fetch all the forms we want to apply custom Bootstrap validation styles to
                var forms = document.getElementsByClassName('needs-validation');
                // Loop over them and prevent submission
                var validation = Array.prototype.filter.call(forms, function (form) {
                    form.addEventListener('submit', function (event) {
                        if (form.checkValidity() === false) {
                            event.preventDefault();
                            event.stopPropagation();
                        } else {
                            try {
                                var data = {
                                    firstname: form.name.value,
                                    lastname: form.lastname.value,
                                    company: form.company.value,
                                    email: form.email.value,
                                    phone: form.phone.value,
                                    jobtitle: form.job.value,
                                    message: form.comments.value,
                                }

                                $.ajax({
                                    type: "POST",
                                    url: url,
                                    data: data
                                });
                            } catch (error) {
                                console.log(error)
                            }
                        }
                        form.classList.add('was-validated');
                    }, false);
                });
            }, false);
        })();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-KyZXEAg3QhqLMpG8r+8fhAXLRk2vvoC2f3B09zVXn8CA5QIVfZOJ3BCsw2P0p/We" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.0/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-U1DAWAznBHeqEIlVSCgzq+c9gqGAJn5c/t99JyeKa9xxaYpSvHU5awsuZVVFIhvj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <section class="section">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-12">
                    <h4 class="text-dark mb-0">Ponte en contacto :</h4>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-12">
                    <div class="custom-form rounded border p-4 h-100">
                        <div id="message"></div>
                        <form class="row g-3 needs-validation" novalidate>
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-6">
                                    <div class="form-group app-label">
                                        <label for="validationCustom01" class="text-muted">Nombre</label>
                                        <input name="name" id="validationCustom01" type="text"
                                            class="form-control resume" placeholder="Ingresa tu nombre" required>
                                        <div class="invalid-feedback pl-2 pt-1">
                                            Ingrese un nombre
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-6">
                                    <div class="form-group app-label">
                                        <label class="text-muted">Apellido</label>
                                        <input name="lastname" id="lastname" type="text" class="form-control resume"
                                            placeholder="Ingresa tu apellido" required>
                                        <div class="invalid-feedback pl-2 pt-1">
                                            Ingrese un apellido
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-4">
                                    <div class="form-group app-label">
                                        <label class="text-muted">Numero de Teléfono</label>
                                        <input name="phone" id="phone1" type="phone" class="form-control resume"
                                            placeholder="Ingresa tu teléfono" required>
                                        <div class="invalid-feedback pl-2 pt-1">
                                            Ingrese un teléfono
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-8">
                                    <div class="form-group app-label">
                                        <label class="text-muted">Correo Electrónico</label>
                                        <input name="email" id="email1" type="email" class="form-control resume"
                                            placeholder="Ingresa tu correo electrónico" required>
                                        <div class="invalid-feedback pl-2 pt-1">
                                            Ingrese un email valido
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-4">
                                    <div class="form-group app-label">
                                        <label class="text-muted">Empresa</label>
                                        <input name="company" type="text" class="form-control resume" id="empresa"
                                            placeholder="Ingresa el nombre de tu empresa" required>
                                        <div class="invalid-feedback pl-2 pt-1">
                                            Ingrese el nombre de su empresa
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-8">
                                    <div class="form-group app-label">
                                        <label class="text-muted">Cargo</label>
                                        <input name="job" type="text" class="form-control resume" id="cargo"
                                            placeholder="Ingresa tu cargo" required>
                                        <div class="invalid-feedback pl-2 pt-1">
                                            Ingrese su cargo
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-12 ">
                                    <div class="form-group app-label">
                                        <label class="text-muted">Mensaje</label>
                                        <textarea name="comments" id="comments" rows="5" class="form-control resume"
                                            placeholder="Cuentanos como podemos ayudarte" required></textarea>
                                        <div class="invalid-feedback pl-2 pt-1">
                                            Ingrese un mensaje
                                        </div>
                                    </div>

                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-sm-12">
                                    <button class="submitBnt btn btn-primary" type="submit">Enviar Mensaje</button>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

Comment: Try opening your script up in the browsers development tools and put in some breakpoints and follow the execution of the code. Make sure your logic doing what you think it is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The ajax part is never reached because the browser is sending the form. To send ajax, prevent the default behaviour and only execute the ajax section when the validation has occurred.

````
   'use strict';
   window.addEventListener('load', function () {
         // Fetch all the forms we want to apply custom Bootstrap validation styles to
         var forms = document.getElementsByClassName('needs-validation');
         // Loop over them and prevent submission
         var validation = Array.prototype.filter.call(forms, function (form) {
            form.addEventListener('submit', function (event) {
               //Prevent the browser default action
               event.preventDefault();
               event.stopPropagation();
               if (form.checkValidity()) {
                     try {
                        var data = {
                           firstname: form.name.value,
                           lastname: form.lastname.value,
                           company: form.company.value,
                           email: form.email.value,
                           phone: form.phone.value,
                           jobtitle: form.job.value,
                           message: form.comments.value,
                        }

                        $.ajax({
                           type: "POST",
                           url: url,
                           data: data
                        });
                     } catch (error) {
                        console.log(error)
                     }
               }
               form.classList.add('was-validated');
            }, false);
         });
   }, false);
})();```
````